# Opening Iframe location in another Tab

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Yeah, I know what you're thinking. The problem is not about opening the links in within the iframe in a new tab, which can be easily solved by adding the target="" attribute.

But what I wanted to do is: I have an iframe which were dynamically created from a form, and it will load the corresponding urls depending on the inputs by the user. What I wanted to do is load the whole iframe in another tab.

Is it doable?

Thanks. Cheers!

Comment: If you're loading a user-inputted URL in an iframe, wouldn't loading "the whole iframe in another tab" just mean opening a new tab with said supplied URL? Unless you want to consistently utilise a specific tab/window over and over again when the user enters a new URL... in which case, open a new window and give it a name, then open the URLs by targeting that name.

Comment: Hello.. sorry for the late reply.. I was processing the iframes in different php file. And the user inputs are not URL's. They are just tags. And I have conditions in a php file, where in I will load a corresponding iframe and urls based on the tags. the iframes are being loaded in another url/page, and i don't know how to open in a new tab. Should i simulate another click event in that page? or is there any better way to do this?